# How to use *Ngfor in an other *Ngfor

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, ngfor

I am trying to create a checkbox for each element of an array "lesCriteres".
Then I want each of these checkboxes to be checked if its value is in the table "actif.lesCriteresActifs"

Here is the code I want but it does not work as I want

```
<div class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let l of lesCriteres">
    <div *ngFor="let a of actif.lesCriteresActifs">
        <label></label>
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChangeEvent(l.code, $event.target.checked)" [checked]="a.critere.code==l.code"> {{l.code}}<br>
     </div>
</div>
```

**MODELS**

*actif model*

```
import {TypeActif} from './model.type-actif';
import {CritereActif} from './model.critere-actif';

export class Actif{
  ref: string;
  nom: string = '';
  type_actif: TypeActif = new TypeActif();
  lesCriteresActifs: Array<CritereActif> = new Array<CritereActif>();
}
```

*CritereActif model*

```
import {Actif} from './model.actif';
import {LesCriteres} from './model.les-criteres';
import {LesValeurs} from './model.les-valeurs';

export class CritereActif{
  id: number;
  actif: Actif = new Actif();
  critere: LesCriteres = new LesCriteres();
  valeur: LesValeurs = new LesValeurs();
}
```

*LesCriteres model*

```
export class LesCriteres{
  code: string = null;
  nom: string = '';
}
```

**RESULT**

i have this when i execute my code :

[image]

but i want't something like this :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you use the index. Once you write "let a of actif.lesCriteresActifs; let i=index", then actif.lesCriteresActifs[i], which you use later in code, is the same thing as "a" ! :D And I am sorry, I still can't quite understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: you're right, i edited it

Comment: each checkbox has a value. I want to look if its value exists in a.critere. if it exists, i check it ! sorry maybe it's because of my english :(

Comment: Now I know what you want to achieve. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: It works !!! thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (using includes() method, without additional *ngFor):

```
<div class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let l of lesCriteres">
        <label></label>
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChangeEvent(l.code, $event.target.checked)" [checked]="actif.lesCriteresActifs.includes(l)"> {{l.code}}<br>
</div>
```

About includes method: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp

EDIT:

This solution comes to mind.
In .ts file of your component, inside class declare a function:

```
containsCode = (code) => {
    for (let a of this.actif.lesCriteresActifs) {
        if (a.critere.code === code) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
```

Then in .html file:

```
<div class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let l of lesCriteres">
        <label></label>
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChangeEvent(l.code, $event.target.checked)" [checked]="containsCode(l.code)"> {{l.code}}<br>
</div>
```

Comment: The comparison is not between an element of actif.lesCriteresActifs and an element of lesCriteres but between an element of lesCriteresActifs.critere and an element of lesCriteres that's why i need the index of the element of lesCriteresActifs

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly. Then in your code, don't you want index of the element "l", not of element "a" ?

Comment: A glimpse to some of your data would help.

Comment: Yeah ! i'm not good in english !! wait, i'll edit my post so that you understand better

Comment: do you understand now ?

Comment: Not really :D For example, if l is the 2nd element of lesCriteres, you want to look at 2nd element lesCriteresActifs? That's why you need index?

Comment: lesCritere is an array : it contains 2 instances of Criteres [{code: C, nom :Confidentialité}, {code: I, nom: Integrité}] ==> so i have 2 checkboxes normally [C and I]

Comment: The second array is lesCriteresAcifs ! i want to verify is there's an element that has the same value of my checkboxes. if there's so i want to check it

Comment: that why i wan't to use the index of lesCriteresActifs and compare each element of lesCriteresActifs [index].critere with lesCriteres

Comment: look at the picture ! the code gives me 4 checkboxes instead of 2 chekboxes

Comment: let me ask you a question. do the index of Criteres and lesCriteresActifs match? Meaning 2 elements in Criteres strictly 2 element in lesCriteresActifs and 1st element of Criteres map to 1st element of lesCriteresActifs?

Comment: No ! Because there are some elements of lesCriteres that aren't in lesCriteresActifs.critere

Comment: Did you get 2 checkboxes after trying the  Róbert Druska Answer or even before that?

Comment: His answer doesn't work because he verifies if "actif.lesCriteresActifs.includes(l)" instead of verying if "actif.lesCriteresActifs[i].critere.includes(l)" ! i mean the comparaison is between "a.critere" and "critere" instead of "a" and "critere"

Comment: Thanks you so much @Róbert Druska !!